# Firebase rules doesn't work on server request but work on Simulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
    "rules": {
        "verifications": {
             // Can only request verification code if it's been one minute than previous request.
            "$phoneNumber": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() || (newData.child('timestamp').val() > data.child('timestamp').val() + 60000)"
            }
        },
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

This rules work on the Firebase Simulator and the writing process got rejected if the timestamp is not later by 1 minute. But when I tried to write from the server, it passed the rules and the writing process was allowed.

The code:

```
var data = {
    timestamp: 1468664575179
};

var phoneNumber = '+14253452';

firebase.database().ref(`verifications/${phoneNumber}`).set(data, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I wonder why the writing process was rejected on the Firebase Simulator but allowed when the request came from the server.

This doesn't give the reason:
[Firebase Security Rules work in simulator, but not in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582287/firebase-security-rules-work-in-simulator-but-not-in-code?rq=1)

Comment: Show an example of your database structure. I feel like `ref('verifications/${+14253452}')` is not right.

Comment: actually it's ${phoneNumber}, the value of phoneNumber is '+14253452'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you initialize the connection.

If your server is running under an unrestricted service account, it will be running with administrative permissions and bypassing the security rules.

```
// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"
});
```

See the [authentication section of the Firebase server docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-authentication).

The same section of the docs explains how you can override this behavior, by giving a `uid` to the server process when you initialize:

```
// Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's access
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "my-service-worker"
  }
});
```